# Student Agency and Life Cycle Management in Salesforce Education Data Architecture

Tags: education-data-architecture

As I am working on EDA(Education data architecture), Here we have a requirment to send an notification to student and faculty when ever an event is scheduled, for that we have an solution called SAL. Need Guidance how to install SAL(student Agency And Life Cycle Management).As I have referred multiple blogs, As mentioned that we will find SAL module under Package page, but I didn't find any module related to SAL.
FYI:[image: Available Module].
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion of SAL standing for `Student Agency and Life Cycle Management` is not a product I've heard of or seen any results in with google.

I believe you are referring to Salesforce Advisor Link (SAL) which was renamed to [Student Success Hub for Higher Education](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJjbtUAD) (SSH). This is listed in that screenshot in your question.